# File is not within the allowed path (Symfony)

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I was doing a non-personal project when I suddenly bumped into this error.

> ContextErrorException in ExecutableFinder.php line 59: 
>  **Warning:**
>   is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib/php) is
>   not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/allservice:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php5:/tmp:/usr/bin/php)

Here's the `phpinfo()` of **open_basedir** settings.

> /var/www/allservice:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php5:/tmp:/usr/bin/php

I'm getting this error on my hosting. In local environment everything works fine. I've tried re-installing Symfony via Composer and cleaning cache. Nothing helps.

Since it stopped working on the hosting and works locally, as far as I understand this may be PHP or Apache settings issue?

Here's the full error.

> 1. in ExecutableFinder.php
>      line 59
> 2. at ErrorHandler->handleError('2',
>      'is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib/php) is
>      not within the allowed path(s):
>      (/var/www/allservice:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php5:/tmp:/usr/bin/php)',
>      '/var/www/allservice/allservice.in.ua/testPHP/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php',
>      '59', *array*('name' => 'java', 'default' =>
>      '/usr/bin/java', 'extraDirs' => *array*(), 'searchPath'
>      => *array*('/var/www/allservice', '/usr/lib/php', '/usr/lib/php5', '/tmp', '/usr/bin/php'), 'dirs' =>
>      *array*('/var/www/allservice'), 'path' =>
>      '/usr/lib/php'))
> 3. at is_dir('/usr/lib/php') in ExecutableFinder.php
>      line 59
> 4. at ExecutableFinder->find('java',
>      '/usr/bin/java') in Configuration.php
>      line 67
> 5. at Configuration->Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DependencyInjection\{closure}()
>      in VariableNode.php
>      line 54
> 6. at VariableNode->getDefaultValue()
>      in ArrayNode.php line 241
> 7. at ArrayNode->finalizeValue(*array*('debug'
>      => *true*, 'use_controller' => *array*('enabled' => *true*), 'bundles' => *array*(), 'filters' => *array*('cssrewrite' => *array*()))) in BaseNode.php
>      line 303
> 8. at BaseNode->finalize(*array*('debug'
>      => *true*, 'use_controller' => *array*('enabled' => *true*), 'bundles' => *array*(), 'filters' => *array*('cssrewrite' => *array*()))) in Processor.php line 37
> 9. at Processor->process(*object*(ArrayNode),
>      *array*(*array*('debug' => *true*,
>      'use_controller' => *false*, 'bundles' =>
>      *array*(), 'filters' => *array*('cssrewrite' =>
>      *null*)), *array*('use_controller' =>
>      *true*))) in Processor.php line 50
> 10. at Processor->processConfiguration(*object*(Configuration),
>       *array*(*array*('debug' => *true*,
>       'use_controller' => *false*, 'bundles' =>
>       *array*(), 'filters' => *array*('cssrewrite' =>
>       *null*)), *array*('use_controller' =>
>       *true*))) in AsseticExtension.php
>       line 44
> 11. at AsseticExtension->load(*array*(*array*('debug'
>       => *true*, 'use_controller' => *false*, 'bundles' => *array*(), 'filters' => *array*('cssrewrite' => *null*)), *array*('use_controller' => *true*)), *object*(ContainerBuilder))
>       in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php
>       line 50
> 12. at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(*object*(ContainerBuilder))
>       in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php
>       line 39
> 13. at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(*object*(ContainerBuilder))
>       in Compiler.php
>       line 117
> 14. at Compiler->compile(*object*(ContainerBuilder))
>       in ContainerBuilder.php
>       line 614
> 15. at ContainerBuilder->compile()
>       in bootstrap.php.cache
>       line 2564
> 16. at Kernel->initializeContainer()
>       in bootstrap.php.cache
>       line 2343
> 17. at Kernel->boot()
>       in bootstrap.php.cache
>       line 2374
> 18. at Kernel->handle(*object*(Request)) in
>       app_dev.php
>       line 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of your hosting PHP configuration.

Basically, they have a `open_basedir` configiration directive set to prevent their clients to mess with files outside their dedicated sandbox.

I see from your stack trace you are trying to locate java executable in `/usr/bin/java` which is not in the `open_basedir` specified paths, hence the error.

You can try to convince the hosting admins to change the directive for you, if they don't, you will not be able to do this.